# JAX-RS Wildfly 14: Unable to Gzip return JSON

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, gzip, wildfly

I am working on `Java EE 8` project and using `Wildfly 14` for deployment. I am trying to Gzip JSON response when `gzipflag: 1` passed in the header of the request, gzip returns `▼` character. Surprisingly, when I am gzipping that JSON through `GZIPOutputStream` myself, I am able to do it.

Here is the code of `Demo` class:

```
package com.demo.boundary;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

/**
 * Demo
 */
@Path("demo")
public class Demo {

    @Path("demo")
    @GET
    public Response readFile() {
        try {
            String jsonFile = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\demo.json")).stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

            GZIPOutputStream gzipStream = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\gzipped.js.gz"));
            gzipStream.write(jsonFile.getBytes());

            gzipStream.finish();
            gzipStream.close();

            return Response.ok(jsonFile).build();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

Here is the code of `GzipFilter` class:

```
package com.demo.config;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class GzipFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
            throws IOException {

        if ((requestContext.getHeaderString("gzipflag") == null
                || requestContext.getHeaderString("gzipflag").equals("1"))) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Gzip flag is ON");

            GZIPOutputStream gzippedOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(responseContext.getEntityStream());
            responseContext.setEntityStream(gzippedOutputStream);

            responseContext.getHeaders().putSingle("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        } else {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Gzip flag is OFF");
        }
    }
}
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: I think Wildfly is not calling `flush` on gzipped stream

Comment: why don't you just configure undertow subsystem to enable gzip filter in case header is set